# ROP - pop eax, ret gadget doesn't work

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, dep

I am building a ROP chain for a security challenge. I have a problem in my ROP chain. I found some interesting gadgets with ropshell.com, and they seem to work pretty well except one. Indeed I follow the stack pointer on gdb peda and only one instruction has a problem which is `pop eax, ret` at the address `0x080a9d36`. This instruction contains no null bytes but the stack pointer apparently doesn't recognize it and send me a segfault `Stopped reason: SIGSEGV - 0x08009d36 in ?? ()`.

I just don't understand why the `0a` becomes suddenly a `00`. Would someone have an idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I found the problem. This is about the fact that the address of this gadget contains 0a which corresponds to a \n